# pulling from file in a certain format python

Tags: python

I have 2 questions:

1. Write a program that retrieves all phone number with format (nnn)nnn-nnnn in a file.
2. Make a program to retrieve every email address ending in .com present in a file

They are different but essentially we want to be checking for certain strings in a file that we read.  So far I can only read the file and put each line into an array.  I'm not sure how to disregard the \n at the end.

Code:

```
newfile = open('filepath')
numfile = newfile.readlines()


numbers = []
for line in num:
    numbers.append(line)

newfile.close

print numbers
```

Comment: should be `numfile ` instead of `num`

Comment: does your `(nnn)nnn-nnnn` match `(010)123-1234` or both `123-1234` and `123456-1234`?

Comment: Only will match.  The others will be over looked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

re module can be used.

```
import re

pattern1 = '\(\d{3}\)\d{3}-\d{4}'
re.findall(pattern1, "My number is (234)456-3678 and your number is (567)789-4567.")
```

Assuming the file has the same content as mentioned in the second parameter of findall.
Similarly create a pattern for email also.
like

```
pattern2 = '[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.com'

re.findall(pattern2, "My email is abc@hotmail.com and your email is abcdef_23@gmail.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

To disregard the \n at the end of each line, you just use .strip("\n") on your lines.

```
for line in num:
    numbers.append(line.strip("\n"))
```

.strip(phrase) will remove any characters from the end of a string matching the phrase in the brackets.

Can you clarify the first part of the question though, please? How is the file structured - will you be searching through the file to find numbers embedded in it, or do you have one number per line? As the user above said, if the latter is the case, then you can use regular expressions in order to search for the phone numbers, otherwise, if the former is true you're right in iterating through the file.

Comment: We will be iterating through to find numbers embedded in it.  So the entire file is just numbers and symbols and we are looking for phone numbers in that.

Comment: Then in that case the other answers are right in saying to use regular expressions to do the searching for you.